# unable to read messages from messages file in unit test

Tags: playframework-2.6

I want to read the error messages from `messages` file but I am unable to. What mistake am I making?

The code where I want to read the string from `messages` file is

```
Future {  Ok(Json.toJson(JsonResultError(messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyType")(langs.availables(0))))) }
```

The `messages` file `error.incorrectBodyType=Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON`

The messagesApi("error.incorrectBodyType") should return `Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON` but it returns `error.incorrectBodyType`.

If I remove double quotes in `messagesApi(error.incorrectBodyType)` then the code doesn't compile

Update

I added a couple of debug prints and notice that the keys I am using in MessagesApi are not defined. I don't know why though as I have created them in `messages` file.

```
println("langs array"+langs.availables)
        println("app.title"+messagesApi.isDefinedAt("app.title")(langs.availables(0)))
        println("error"+messagesApi.isDefinedAt("error.incorrectBodyType")(langs.availables(0)))
```

prints

```
langs arrayList(Lang(en_GB))
app.titlefalse
errorfalse
```

Update 2
I might have found the issue but I don't know how to resolve it. Basically, I am running my test case without an instance of the `Application`. I am `mocking` messagesApi by calling `stubMessagesApi()` defined in `Helpers.stubControllerComponents`, If I run the same code using an `Application` eg `class UserControllerFunctionalSpec extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuiteWithComponents` then `app.title` and `error` are defined. It seems without an instance of `Application`, `MessagesApi` is not using the `messages` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by creating a new instance of `MessagesApi` using `DefaultMessagesApi`

```
val messagesApi = new DefaultMessagesApi( //takes map of maps. the first is the language file, the 2nd is the map between message title and description
    Map("en" -> //the language file
      Map("error.incorrectBodyType" -> "Incorrect body type. Body type must be JSON") //map between message title and description
    )
  )
  val controller = new UserController(mockUserRepository,mockControllerComponents,mockSilhouette,messagesApi,stubLangs())
```